# PHP header ("Location:...") no redirecciona en app React

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

Tengo una aplicación React que usa React Router para el manejo de las url y que consume datos por api en PHP mediante axios.
Desde la primer pantalla al ingresar al sitio por navegador, se hace pedido de datos a la API.
En el código de PHP se realiza la conexión a la base de datos con un try, catch.
Cuando fuerzo a incorrectos los valores para el acceso a la base de datos, el código entra por el catch y realiza lo siguiente:

`catch (Exception $ex) { header("Location: ../screens/error.html"); die('No se pudo conectar'); }`

Pero en lugar de redirigir a error.html, en mi navegador se queda la pantalla en blanco.
El código fuente que muestra la página en blanco sigue siendo código javascript.
La URL se mantiene en la misma que la página de inicio de la app react.

Desde la pestaña Network del DevTools puedo ver que aparece el archivo error.html al que quiero acceder,con la URL correcta para su ubicación en el servidor, y con status 302. En Response aparece el contenido del archivo error.html

Ayuda por favor, no encuentro el problema.

Comment: ¿Y si miras el código fuente de esa pantalla en blanco que se ve?  Quizas estas ocultando la salida de algun modo o no muestras nada en el error.html (digo yo, no lo se, pero es raro que lo veas cargado con el status 200 y que veas una response con datos, pero no en la ventana)

Comment: Necesitas proveer más información sobre el problema, por favor revisa las secciones de ayuda de la comunidad para saber cómo formular una buena pregunta.

Comment: El código fuente de la pantalla en blanco es el del front que se vería normalmente con datos obtenidos del pedido, es decir del build de react. Pero al no obtener datos se ve la pantalla blanca porque dan undefined las variables de javascript. Tal vez hay que permitir el uso de header(location..) desde alguna configuración y no se dónde se aplica.

Comment: También probé redirigir a la URL absoluta del archivo .html en el header(location...) en vez de la relativa. Esta vez obtuve un error net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Comment: ah, jolin, que estas usando React... cosa que desconozco... entonces lo que haces es llamar a PHP con una llamada tipo ajax supongo... no creo que eso te funcione

Comment: Perdón, creo que fui poco claro, voy a editar mi pregunta para aportar mas información sobre el problema.